# express return erros as JSON instead HTML

Tags: node.js, express

I'm developing simple api with `ExpressJS` and when an error generated in express (out of my control, ex: `express-jwt` middleware or some 404 error etc.), it returns a html response.
Tried changing request headers in postman but same. I tried `body-parser` and setting `content-type` header in middleware also.

But all responses I send with `res.send()` works normally.

This is a 404 error I got.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">>Error</title>
    </head><body><pre>Cannot GET /test</pre></body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to set response type globally to the app? Or is this because something I do wrong in postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can add a error handler after adding  all the routes .

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.message); // Log error message in our server's console
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500; // If err has no specified error code, set error code to 'Internal Server Error (500)'
  res.status(err.statusCode).send({error : err.message}); // All HTTP requests must have a response, so let's send back an error with its status
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Using above code with `http-errors` [https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-errors] is recommended.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioBarisich In ideal case Server error messages & stack traces should be not be exposed in response for security reasons .
If for development purposes you want to send stack in response `err.stack` would contain the stack .
For Production. logs can be linked to a hash value sent in response to make logs easily searchable

Comment: @ShreyGupta I been talking about server logs, not http responses.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioBarisich
For 404 errors you will need a catch all route `app.use((req, res)=>{})`